# NameError with super() inside decorator

Tags: python, python-2.7, super, python-decorators

Using python 2.7

I'm creating a library of objects on import using decorators, and while importing I do some checks on the instance of each object; mostly duplication checks...

I've recently made the switch to using `super()` to take advantage of its multiple-inheritance handling, but it raises a `NameError` on the object being instantiated.

#### Simplified code highlighting issue:

```
class Lib(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "library created"
        self.lib = {}

    def add_obj(self, obj):
        print "object being added to library --> %s" % obj.__name__
        inst = obj()
        print inst.name
        self.lib[obj.__name__] = obj

def Reg(obj):
    global test_lib
    test_lib.add_obj(obj)

test_lib = Lib()

@Reg
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        object.__init__(self)
        self.name = "A instance"

@Reg
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.name = "B instance"
```

#### Output

```
>>> from testing import *
library created
object being added to library --> A
A instance
object being added to library --> B
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "testing.py", line 25, in <module>
    class B(object):
  File "testing.py", line 14, in Reg
    test_lib.add_obj(obj)
  File "testing.py", line 8, in add_obj
    inst = obj()
  File "testing.py", line 27, in __init__
    super(B, self).__init__()
NameError: global name 'B' is not defined
```

It seems like there's a scoping issue? Excluding the decorator, class B instantiates without a problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to instantiate `B` before it has finished being defined.

#### Fix it:

Remove these lines from `Lib.add_obj()`:

```
inst = obj()
print inst.name
```

#### Why?

The decorator `Reg` is involved in the definition of `B`.  So you will not be able to instantiate `B`, via that name, until `Reg` has exited.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for the response. I'm instantiating inside Lib.add_obj() as I want to do some error checking on the instance, so it's in there to serve a purpose.

Can you elaborate on "Reg is involved in the definition of B". How come Reg doesn't affect definition of A in the same manner?

Comment: You can not do that if you want to use the name `B` in super, because `B` does not exist until the decorator exits.